# Automated test class isn't being generated for my stubs

Tags: spring-boot, stub, spring-cloud-contract

The automated test class isn't being generated for my stubs. It was, at some point, but now it's stopped.

My base test class:

```
package address;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import CustomerPreviousAddressApplication;

import PreviousAddressController;
import io.restassured.module.mockmvc.RestAssuredMockMvc;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = CustomerPreviousAddressApplication.class)
public abstract class PreviousAddressBaseTest {

    @Autowired
    private PreviousAddressController previousAddressController;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(previousAddressController);
    }
}
```

The actual stub:

```
package contracts

import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract


Contract.make {

    description ""

    request {
        url("/previous-address")
        method GET()
    }
    response {
        status 200
        headers {
            header(
                    'Content-Type', value(consumer('text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1'), producer(regex('text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1')))
            )
        }
        body(
                "Send me something!"
        )
    }
}
```

And I've included the following dependancy in my pom file:

```
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <!-- <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version> -->
          <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
          <extensions>true</extensions>
          <configuration>
            <baseClassForTests>
                address.PreviousAddressBaseTest
            </baseClassForTests>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
```

Shouldn't that be all I need to make it work? And yet, the test file isn't being generated

Comment: Yes it should. Version 1.2.2 seems really old so please use the latest available one. Also, we would need to see some stacktrace or part of the log execution to see what's wrong. Where are your contracts stored? Maybe you've changed the location? Also, why do you use the standalone setup if you're injecting the controller there? It's better to setup the controller manually without starting the context. BTW Your `content-type` header looks strange. There's no regex in the producer side. Just set the `headers { contentType(textPlain())}`.

Comment: Yeah I actually originally had the version at "2.1.1.RELEASE", but then I was looking at an example of a working stub, and they had the version at Version 1.2.2, so I was just trying to match that example. The problem still happens when I have the version set at "2.1.1.RELEASE". My contracts are stored in "test/resources/contracts". I'm not sure what part of the log I could show you. The project builds successfully without any errors. "why do you use the standalone setup if you're injecting the controller there" - Sorry, what do you mean by this exactly? I'm very new to all of this

Comment: You can check out the samples https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/tree/master/producer with a setup that works

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

which according to the doc is responsible for generating test code based on the contract file.

Doc: https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-contract